# How do you copy between arrays of different sizes in Rust?

Tags: arrays, rust

If I have two arrays of different sizes:

```
let mut array1 = [0; 8];
let array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

How would I copy `array2` into the first 4 bytes of `array1`?  I can take a mutable 4 byte slice of array1, but I'm not sure how or if I can assign into it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most flexible way is to use iterators to handle each element successively:

```
for (place, data) in array1.iter_mut().zip(array2.iter()) {
    *place = *data
}
```

[`.mut_iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/slice/trait.MutableVector.html#tymethod.mut_iter) creates [an `Iterator` that yields `&mut u8`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/slice/struct.MutItems.html), that is, mutable references pointing into the slice/array. [`iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/slice/trait.ImmutableVector.html#tymethod.iter) does the same but with [shared references](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/slice/struct.Items.html). [`.zip`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#tymethod.zip) takes two iterators and steps over them in lock-step, yielding the elements from both as a tuple (and stops as soon as either one stops).

If you need/want to do anything 'fancy' with the data before writing to `place` this is the approach to use.

However, the plain copying functionality is also provided as single methods,

- [`.copy_from`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/slice/trait.MutableCloneableVector.html#tymethod.copy_from), used like `array1.copy_from(array2)`.
- [`std::slice::bytes::copy_memory`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/master/std/slice/bytes/fn.copy_memory.html), although you will need to trim the two arrays because `copy_memory` requires they are the same length:

  ```
  use std::cmp;
  use std::slice::bytes;

  let len = cmp::min(array1.len(), array2.len());
  bytes::copy_memory(array1.mut_slice_to(len), array2.slice_to(len));
  ```

  (If you know that `array1` is always longer than `array2` then `bytes::copy_memory(array1.mut_slice_to(array2.len()), array2)` should also work.)

At the moment, the `bytes` version optimises the best, down to a `memcpy` call, but hopefully `rustc`/LLVM improvements will eventually take them all to that.

Comment: Note that `mut_iter` has been renamed to `iter_mut` at least since 1.0.0 (probably earlier?)

Comment: Can confirm, WiSaGaN. Edited the answer to add your correction.

Answer (score 15):

Manually one can do

```
for (dst, src) in array1.iter_mut().zip(&array2) {
    *dst = *src
}
```

for a typical slice. However, there is a likely faster specialization in `clone_from_slice`:

```
dst[..4].clone_from_slice(&src)
```

A slightly older method is to use `std::io::Write`, which was implemented for `&mut [u8]`.

```
use std::io::Write;
let _ = dst.write(&src)
```

This will write *up to* the end of `dst` and return how many values were written in a `Result`. If you use `write_all`, this will return an `Err` if not all bytes could be written.

Answer (score 7):

You could simply use [`copy_from_slice()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.copy_from_slice) and use [`Range & Co`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut dest = [0; 8];
    let src = [1, 2, 3, 4];

    dest[..4].copy_from_slice(&src);

    assert_eq!(dest, [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0]);
}
```

Inverse case:

```
fn main() {
    let src = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    let mut dest = [0; 4];

    dest.copy_from_slice(&src[2..6]);

    assert_eq!(dest, [3, 4 ,5, 6]);
}
```

Combined case:

```rust
fn main() {
    let src = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    let mut dest = [0; 4];

    dest[1..3].copy_from_slice(&src[3..5]);

    assert_eq!(dest, [0, 4, 5, 0]);
}
```

---

Tips, you can use the Range twice to avoid calculation mistake:

```rust
fn main() {
    let src = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
    let mut dest = [0; 4];
    let len = dest.len();

    dest.copy_from_slice(&src[2..][..len]);

    assert_eq!(dest, [3, 4 ,5, 6]);
}
```

Comment: How could I modify your first example to fill the destination array with the `src` array repeatedly in the most idiomatic / fastest way? e.g. `assert_eq!(dest, [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]);` At first glance it may look like one would want that behavior to panic because there's no way to know if `src` fits within `dest` but presumably one could just check if the lengths are divisible

Comment: @airstrike see other answer with `.zip()` and use `repeat()`