# How to copy to slice with different size in Rust?

Tags: rust

`copy_from_slice` requires the source and destination slices to have the same lenght.

How can I copy from a slice smaller than its destination?

The closest I found was [How do you copy between arrays of different sizes in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25225346/6655884), it lists

```
for (dst, src) in slice_destination.iter_mut().zip(slice_source) {
    *dst = *src
}
```

It worked for me. But is there an easier way?

Comment: It would be great if you could include a more complete example. Also, if the slices are different sizes, can you create a new slice that is a subset of the longer one with the length of the smaller one, and then copy using those instead?

Comment: Added your answer to your duplicate ;)